# How to set installation checking in an installer generated with iceberg?

Tags: installation

How to set installation checking in an installer generated with iceberg ?

I have followed instructions from here: http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Iceberg/English.lproj/documentation/Scripts%20Pane.html#4

I am trying to add an InstallationCheck script to my installer in order to perform some extra checking before installing.
My installer is generated with iceberg.

I added a script named InstallationCheck to the list of resources of the installer.

In order to check that the script has been properly added to the installer and is invoked by the installer, the script just returns 64.
This scripts returns 64 thus installation should fail.
Unfortunately the installation does not fail.

I have checked that the script has been added to the resources.

My conclusion is that the script is not invoked for a reason that I ignore.

Comment: Have you found a solution? A have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My installer used to have requirements.
There is actually an incompatibility between requirements and InstallationCheck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the filename and syntax of your script (may be you forgot `#!/usr/bin/BASH_OR_PERL_OR_SOMTHING`).

If your script was added to Resources in your pkg, Installer.app must invoke it.